# Python safe dictionary key access

Tags: python, dictionary, logical-operators

I am looking for a convenient, safe python dictionary key access approach. Here are 3 ways came to my mind.

```py
data = {'color': 'yellow'}

# approach one
color_1 = None
if 'color' in data:
    color_1 = data['color']

# approach two
color_2 = data['color'] if 'color' in data else None


# approach three
def safe(obj, key):
    if key in obj:
        return obj[key]
    else:
        return None

color_3 = safe(data, 'color')

#output
print("{},{},{}".format(color_1, color_2, color_3))
```

All three methods work, of-course. But is there any simple out of the box  way to achieve this without having to use excess `if`s or custom functions?

I believe there should be, because this is a very common usage.

Comment: You mean you want to return a default if the key is missing? Then use `dict.get()`.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You missed the canonical method, [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
color_1 = data.get('color')
```

It'll return `None` if the key is missing. You can set a different default as a second argument:

```
color_2 = data.get('color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 14):

Check out [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get). You can supply a value to return if the key is not found in the dictionary, otherwise it will return `None`.

```
>>> data = {'color': 'yellow'}
>>> data.get('color')
'yellow'
>>> data.get('name') is None
True
>>> data.get('name', 'nothing')
'nothing'
```